# How is force related to the non-linear movement of lifting a box co-operatively, while balancing it at each time step?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque, free-body-diagram

[image: A long object Co-lifted by two people]

I have a doubt about the figure mentioned below. Imagine a long object lifted by two people , where one is leading the task and the other is follower , who follows the lifting of the object. After the object is lifted by 20 degrees from one end, the amount of force required by the follower would be?

what if the leader lifts the object with a varying speed , how can the object be balanced by the follower?
Similarly , How the value of force required for the follower change when the leader moves it in other directions like left or right?

Please guide me for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the Force exerted by the object (In this case, weight) is concentrated at the center of gravity. So here the weight of the object would be concentrated at the point where the diagonals meet. Now, if you tilt the object the the center of gravity of the object does not change unless the mass of the body gets redistributed on tilting. And the force will be acting in the direction of gravity and the follower will experience more force since the weight would be directed towards his side.